# Can I make two groups of regex match in same quantity?

Tags: regex

I want a regex that matches the following pattern:

```
b
abc
aabcc
aaabccc
```

But does NOT match any of:

```
ab
bc
aabc
abcc
```

Basically, `/(a)*b(c){_Q_}/`, where `_Q_` is the number of times that group 1 matched. I know how to match group 1 **content** later in the string, but how can I match group 1 **count**?

Comment: What **language** are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this recursive regex:

```
^(a(?:(?1)|b)c)$|^(b)$
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/268)

The regex can be further reduced to:

```
^(a(?1)c|b)$
```

[**Demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/jY3vA1/1)

The alternation consists of:

- The base case `b`
- The recursive case `a(?1)c` which matches `a`, then recurse into group 1, then matches `c`. Group 1 is the alternation itself, so it can contain more pairs of `a` and `c`, or the recursion ends at base case `b`.